# Controlled Rollout not working

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

We have a Chrome app with more than 10k users and we started rolling out a new version yesterday using the Controlled Rollout option on Chrome Web Store set to 1%. Surprisingly more than 2000 users got upgraded. I was expecting a number around 100 users.

Does anybody know if this option is not working anymore?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Report it on their support forum or site.

Comment: Try asking/posting in the [chromium bug list](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list), they should be able to answer the issue you've encountered. Also it would be nice to post that bug link here, there maybe other developers that encountered this issue.

Comment: I started a new release at 5% and this time it worked a little better. The numbers still don't make much sense, but the updates were slower this time. I contacted Chrome Web Store support and I'm waiting for a response. Cheers!